# Python 3.6 Installation

Tags: python, pycharm, installation, python-3.6

I tried to run a predefined installation and this error occurred:

> [1EF0:236C][2019-12-30T15:04:35]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed.

But, I need Python 3.6 for pyaudio and although I don't want to delete Python 3.7! What should I do?

Comment: have you looked at using something like `virtualenv` to create multiple environments? maybe something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) can get you started in the right direction!

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can use the [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) to run different versions of Python.

Comment: @MatR, @martineau! I'm using PyCharm. Doesn't it create virtual environments by itself?

Comment: I have no idea. Suggest you tag your question with "pycharm".

Comment: Use a virtualenv you can create as many as you like and its less "PT" to setup its basically pip install python==3.6 and you are set

Comment: To create a virtual env of Python (for a specific version), you need that version of python installed to create the virtual env with, so the comments relating to virtual environments are pointless.

Comment: I am having the same issue, having installed Python 3.10.0 and now needing to install Python 3.9.6 for a specific task that requires that exact version - this is very frustrating, not sure what the Python devs / installer team was thinking.  As of 2021-10-18, this is still an issue - very frustrating.

Comment: The comment of using Python Launcher, fails to understand the issue.  That comment doe snot help, not in the least.